# Spring IoC: Reasons to have null checks with constructor autowiring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-ioc

What are the reasons to use null checks in spring autowring?

For instance, I often see code like this:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    private final MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    public MyComponent(MyService myService) {
        Assert.notNull(myService, "myService must not be null");
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}
```

What is the point of `Assert.notNull()` call here?

If I forget to declare `MyService` as a Bean Spring will fail with:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.company.MyService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Of course there are some corner cases in which under certain specific conditions it is possible to autowire null bean. But how important are these cases in real well designed code?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the point of Assert.notNull() call here?

In this case, you autowire by a constructor and the purpose of the assertion is to make sure the service has been injected anything but `null` correctly *before* it causes any troubles in the future. Although the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` is thrown when no bean of a correct type has been defined, the `null` still might be injected and the autowiring mechanism doesn't handle it, because it's not its purpose.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is that even if you want to artificially model a situation where null is injected it is not so simple. I had to google how to do that. In this perspective it is not useful to write asserts.

Answer (score 1):

The code is pointless. Spring will throw a ***NoSuchBeanDefinitionException*** if no candidate bean is found in the context. This a core behavior of the framework and I don't see any reason to second guess it.

You can specify that an autowired bean be optional:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
```

but then the null check makes even less sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful when any developer does object creation in plain Java way something like `"new Bean(null)"` Or it is also possible to pass `null` as the value in XML based injection using the `"null"` tag. In both these cases, this assert will shout while bean creation itself.